# Why is co-P = P

Tags: complexity-theory

More specifically why is there a TM that accepts and halts for any complement language in P?
I understand, that there is a TM that rejects a language L from P, but why must there be a TM that accepts the complement of L?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple solution: Let L be the original language with Turing Machine M that accepts the language L. To compute L-complement, create a new machine M' such that M' is the same as M, except we switch all transitions to the accept state of M to a "reject state", and all transitions to a reject state (or a "malformed transition") to the accept state.

The running time for M' is the same as the running time for M. It will accept/reject exactly when M rejects/accepts.

---

A commenter asked if I could provide intuition for why this does not work for NP vs co-NP. It helps here to start with the Cook-Levin definition of a language L being in NP, which allows a clear definition of a language L' being in co-NP. (Using the definition based on Non-deterministic Turing machines makes the definition of co-NP a bit harder)

In the Cook-Levin definition, a language L is in NP, if we have a "verifying" Turing Machine V such that for all strings S in L, there is a polynomially-length bounded certificate string C such that V accepts the pair (S, C) (think of V either as a two-tape input machine, or else think of it as accepting the encoding of the pair of inputs). In addition of course, we have the requirement that V complete the verification in polynomial time.

As an example, for the 3SAT language, the strings S would be 3SAT problem instance statements, and the certificate C would be the truth-assignments to the variables. The verifier V would look at the truth-assignments and check if each clause of the 3SAT problem instance is verified with that truth assignment.

So put succinctly for a language L in NP is described by its verifying Turing machine V, and we say that:

[image]

So to describe the complement language, L' we have:

[image]

If we wanted to 'try the same trick' for NP vs co-NP as we did for P vs co-P, the opportunity does not really present itself well. We either need to try this for a deterministic Turing machine that completely solves the language for every instance (and will probably not have a polynomial-time running bound), or we need to see if we can make it work by applying the trick to V. If we simply swap around the results for the verifying machine V, we still need to check *every* possible certificate C to see if a given string S is truly not accepted by V.

Comment: This is an absolutely correct argument. Could you give some intuition on why this argument fails for NP and co-NP?

Comment: But maybe there are some words in complement of L for which the TM M doesnt halt, those will not be accepted by M'

Comment: Fair enough, but if the language L actually is in P then there is - by definition - a Turing Machine that "decides" the language. Which is to say, for every string S, the Turing Machine accepts or rejects S, and it does so in Polynomial time. If you happened to encounter a malformed machine that only accepts the input if S is in the language, but might fail to halt if S is not in the language, as long as you have a run-time bounds for acceptance, you can "repair" the Turing machine by simulating its run for a number of steps and then rejecting if it has not reached the accept state.